# Locating a element in Python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I'm writing a script in python and I'm having a problem locating an element in this website:https://www.charika.ma/societe-rechercher.

I want to pass to the middle: div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 middle-side". to extract the information in the middle. I'm using this script :

```
try:
row = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "col-md-7 col-sm-7 middle-side"))
)
print(row.text)

except:
    driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way would be to find element by class looks like "middle-side" is enough to go of. Have you tried?

```
a = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("middle-side")
```

Comment: i get this msg, please explain to me:

print(div.text)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: You've not clarified what div.text is. I'm assuming you have set div to = "middle-side" element. Like how I've set 'a' above. If so "middle-side" don't have any text element's hence the error. It has more div element's i would look for all of the "ligne-resulta" as i'm guessing that's what your looking for. Then get the individual element's for each  row. I can't be more specific than that as your not being clear but i recommend reading the selenium documentation https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/index.html

Comment: i'm not sure where to look,

Comment: i'm trying to locate the rows then locate the body, then the headers, then click for each header one by one, thank you